# SQL report filtering, results stop after first item

Tags: sql, filter, reporting

and thanks in advance. I am a newbie, working on one of my first reports. I have orders, which have a terminal  assigned them (a "DC"). The report is set up to return all open orders, the "DC", and a few other columns (driver #, city, etc). I made a drop down filter to use so I can look at one, several, or all of the DCs. My problem is, it stops looking after the first item that is checked in the drop down list. So if the first item in the list has 100 orders, but the rest of them have thousands more, it only shows me the 100 orders. Am I making any sense here? I am not sure what information from my report's setup would be pertinent here.

This is the query that the report is based on. Using SQL Report Builder.

```
SELECT
o.OrderTrackingID,
cm.accountno,
o.ClientRefNo,
o.DCoName,
o.DStreet,
o.DCity,
o.DState,
o.DZip,
o.DZone,
t.TerminalName as 'OrderDC',
e.LastName as 'DrvLast',
e.FirstName as 'DrvFirst',
e.DriverNo,
et.TerminalName as 'DriverDC'
FROM Orders o
FULL JOIN OrderDrivers od ON o.OrderTrackingID = od.OrderTrackingID
FULL JOIN Employees e ON od.DriverID = e.ID
FULL JOIN ClientMaster cm ON o.ClientID = cm.ClientID
FULL JOIN Terminals t ON o.TerminalID = t.TerminalID
FULL JOIN Terminals et ON e.TerminalID = et.TerminalID
WHERE o.Status = 'N'
Order By o.aTimeStamp ASC
```

Comment: The report is based on the query above

Comment: Add that query to your question instead. Is this question about sql or some reporting tool, it is not clear to me?

Comment: Does your report tool have some kind of row limit setting?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I am not sure I would know where to look for that.

Answer (score 0):

(I am writing this as an answer even if it isn't an complete answer mostly because the comment field is kind of limited.)

In the SQL you posted the below stands out as wrong

```
FULL JOIN Terminals t ON o.TerminalID = t.TerminalID
FULL JOIN Terminals et ON e.TerminalID = et.TerminalID
```

You are joining the same table twice but the is nothing that separated the two joins and this is my guess why you are not getting any more orders in your report.

I don't now what the drop down list corresponds to but I assume it is some kind of identifier in the `Terminals` table.

From a pure SQL point of view I would expect something like this

```
FULL JOIN Terminals t ON o.TerminalID = t.TerminalID
WHERE t.someColumn IN (value1, value2)
```

where value1 and value2 comes from the drop down list.

I see in your select part that you include the same column from both of the Terminals JOIN you have and I expect those two columns to always have the same values. You should need that column only once in your select list.

Not a solution but maybe this can get you in the right direction.

Comment: I will play around with this. It sounds logical. As a background explanation, the employee terminal is the terminal that an driver is assigned to while the order terminal is where an order's account is assigned. They are not necessarily the same. Hence the join. I appreciate your advice. Thanks.